# Are there any points for tag creation?

Tags: discussion, tags

I had created at least 8 tags in past and was wondering if there are any points for that.

I'd also like to know identify the tags I've created or who has created a specific tag.

[image: whatISeeOnLearnMore]

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no reputation available for that. It might create bad incentives to produce useless tags :-)

The list of things you gain reputation for is here:

[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

You can see the edits to the tag description and the tag excerpt description under Tags > specific tag > Learn more > History, but that only shows the history of the descriptions, not the creation of the tag itself. If no-one has written a description, the History link won't be there.

Comment: that is fine, but how can I identify which tags I created or who has created what tag ?

Comment: Tags > specific tag > learn more> History  This shows editing back to creation. (unless this is mod-only, but I don't see any need for that.)

Comment: @jtp-apologise-to-monica Thanks, i can go up to ***learn more*** in Tags > specific tag but don't see History.

Comment: @Raj The link is below the description on the "Learn more" page, next to where it says "Edit Tag Info". I can see it even on SE sites where I don't have much reputation, see e.g. https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/2853/revisions

Comment: @@jtp-apologise-to-monica I have added the question to show the picture on what I see

Comment: @Raj Oh, that's because it doesn't have any history yet.